# C++ gcc 9.3.0 typeid of derived pointer always return typeid(BaseClass*) but dynamic_cast<derived_ptr> works fine

Tags: c++, gcc, rtti, dynamic-cast, typeid

There are a few similar posts, here is my minimal case code:

```
bool useDerived=true;
BaseClass* maker;
if (useDerived) {
    maker = new DerivedClass();
}
else {
    maker = new BaseClass();
}
if (typeid(maker) == typeid(DerivedClass*)) {
    cerr << "is derived type\n";
}
else {
    cerr << "not derived type\n";
}
DerivedClass* x = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(maker);
if (x == nullptr) {
    cerr << " cannot cast back to derived\n";
}
else {
    cerr << " cast to derived OK\n";
}
```

The result is:

```
not derived type
cast to derived OK
```

Am I missing something here?  I include the `<typeinfo>` header.  Could it be a compiler version-specific bug?

The `DerivedClass` is derived from the `BaseClass`, and the `DerivedClass` implements several virtual functions from the `BaseClass`.  The idea to use typeid is based on the [blog](https://blog.panicsoftware.com/dynamic_cast-and-typeid-as-non-rtti-tools/) section: Typeid as faster dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeid` is evaluated statically [in this case](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). You should have dereferenced so you would give it a glvalue of polymorphic type, instead of some pointer type.

This line:

```
if (typeid(maker) == typeid(DerivedClass*)) {
```

should be:

```
if (typeid(*maker) == typeid(DerivedClass)) {
```

Comment: This is the solution that I was looking for. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug here.

`typeid()` is evaluated at compile-time.  `BaseClass*` and `DerivedClass*` are two completely different pointer types, so comparing their respective `std::type_info` structs will never compare as equal.

`dynamic_cast` is evaluated at runtime.  Casting a `BaseClass*` pointer to a `DerivedClass*` pointer will invoke an RTTI lookup to find and return a pointer to the `DerivedClass` portion of the object that the `BaseClass*` pointer is pointing at.  If the object does not implement `DerivedClass`, `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr`.

Comment: In this case, `typeid` is evaluated statically. OP's bug is small but significant.